# Storing $_POST with multi-dimensional array in mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, multidimensional-array, calendar

I have a calendar for which each day has a checkbox like this:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="uevent['.$urange.']['.$list_day.']['.$month.']['.$year.']" value="0"><input type="checkbox" id="calendarcheck" name="uevent['.$urange.']['.$list_day.']['.$month.']['.$year.']" checked>$list_day
```

where $urange is one type of calendar out of three.

When submit is clicked, I would like to store in mysql each day whether it was checked or not. So I generated this code:

```
    print_r($_POST);

    $big_query='INSERT INTO `sdcheckings` (`email`,`urange`,`cyear`,`cmonth`,`cday`,`dchecked`,`tcheck`) VALUES ';

    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST[$row[0]]);$i++)
    {
        for($j=0;$j<count($_POST[$row[0]][$i]);$j++)
        {
            for($k=0;$k<count($_POST[$row[0]][$i][$j]);$k++)
            {
                if($k!=0)
                    $big_query.=', ';
                $dchecked = $_POST[$row[0]][$i][$j][$k];
                $big_query.='('.$_SESSION['email'].',  '.$row[0].',  '.$i.',  '.$j.',  '.$k.', '.$dchecked.', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) ';
            }
        }
    }
     $adddates = mysql_query($big_query);
```

When I tested it by checking a couple of dates (february 4th, 2016 and februray 12th, 2016), I got the following:

> Array ( [uevent] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [4] => Array ( [02] =>
>   Array ( [2016] => on ) [3] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) ) [5] => Array (
>   [02] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) [3] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) ) [6] =>
>   Array ( [02] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) [3] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) )
>   [7] => Array ( [02] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) [3] => Array ( [2016] =>
>   0 ) ) [8] => Array ( [02] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) [3] => Array (
>   [2016] => 0 ) ) [9] => Array ( [02] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) [3] =>
>   Array ( [2016] => 0 ) ) [10] => Array ( [02] => Array ( [2016] => 0 )
>   [3] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) ) [11] => Array ( [02] => Array ( [2016]
>   => 0 ) [3] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) ) [12] => Array ( [02] => Array ( [2016] => on ) [3] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) ) [13] => Array ( [02] =>
>   Array ( [2016] => 0 ) [3] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) ) [14] => Array (
>   [02] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) [3] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) ) [15] =>
>   Array ( [02] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) [3] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) )
>   [16] => Array ( [02] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) [3] => Array ( [2016] =>
>   0 ) ) [17] => Array ( [02] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) [3] => Array (
>   [2016] => 0 ) ) [18] => Array ( [02] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) [3] =>
>   Array ( [2016] => 0 ) ) [19] => Array ( [02] => Array ( [2016] => 0 )
>   [3] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) ) [20] => Array ( [02] => Array ( [2016]
>   => 0 ) [3] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) ) [21] => Array ( [02] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) [3] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) ) [22] => Array ( [02] =>
>   Array ( [2016] => 0 ) [3] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) ) [23] => Array (
>   [02] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) [3] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) ) [24] =>
>   Array ( [02] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) [3] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) )
>   [25] => Array ( [02] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) [3] => Array ( [2016] =>
>   0 ) ) [26] => Array ( [02] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) [3] => Array (
>   [2016] => 0 ) ) [27] => Array ( [02] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) [3] =>
>   Array ( [2016] => 0 ) ) [28] => Array ( [02] => Array ( [2016] => 0 )
>   [3] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) ) [29] => Array ( [02] => Array ( [2016]
>   => 0 ) [3] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) ) [1] => Array ( [3] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) ) [2] => Array ( [3] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) ) [3] =>
>   Array ( [3] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) ) [30] => Array ( [3] => Array (
>   [2016] => 0 ) ) [31] => Array ( [3] => Array ( [2016] => 0 ) ) ) )
>   [submit] => Update )

The database did not store anything. I suspect that my loops are not correct. How can that be done?

when printing out at the end $big_query, I get just this:

```
INSERT INTO `sdcheckings` (`email`,`urange`,`gender`,`cyear`,`cmonth`,`cday`,`dchecked`,`tcheck`) VALUES
```

Comment: I hope you know that SQL is fundamentally 2 dimensional.

Comment: php will not post checkboxes that are not checked

Comment: Yes SZenC as you can see in the mySQL query I am storing in 2 dimensions

Comment: the solution to post unchecked checkboxes as well is to put a hidden input with the same name as the checkbox that might not be checked. So that if the checkbox isn't checked, the hidden input is still successful and sent to the server but if the checkbox is checked it will override the hidden input before it.

Comment: @LuthandoLoot or in php you can use a ternary, instead of a hidden input - ie. `$value = isset($_POST['checkbox']) ? true : false;`. Also, the hidden input would need to be before the checkbox in the form document, or it will override the checkbox even when checked.

Comment: @Sean yes you're right. I think we have given the OP enough info to solve his/her problem(unchecked boxes)

Comment: Sean I was not able to understand how to implement the ternary, but LuthandoLoot I was able to make unchecked checkbox value "0" passed through hidden input right before each one. Thanks! Now I am still struggling with how to to loop around the $_POST to pass all the data to mySQL query. The first dimension will always remain the same, but the next 3 dimension represent day, month and year respectively.

Comment: @Tuntex please print your query string and show us the results `echo $big_query;`

Comment: LuthandoLoot: I get just this (see updated post). Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: @Tuntex it doesn't go inside the loop, please check if your `$row` has the correct data

Comment: Thanks Luthando Loot! That helped narrow down where the issues where from. It was a combination of syntax, the logic behind the data structure, and learnt to use function key() in order to get the value of the index element.

Answer (score 0):

```
        foreach($_POST['uevent'][$row[0]] as $yearnum => $postyear)
        {
            foreach($postyear as $monthnum => $postmonth)
            {
                foreach($postmonth as $daynum => $postday)
                {
                    if($firstcoma>0)
                        $big_query.=', ';
                    $firstcoma++;

                    if(strcmp($postday,"on")==0)
                        $postday=1;

                    $big_query.='("'.$_SESSION['email'].'",  '.$row[0].',  "'.$row[1].'",  '.$yearnum.',  '.$monthnum.',  '.$daynum.', '.$postday.', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) ';
                }
            }
        }
```